# EditText gives NullPointerException on getText

Tags: java, android, function, android-edittext, gettext

I'm  kinda new and any help would be appreciated
Currently either it's filled it in or I'm getting a toast saying there is a nullpointer.
In the if else statement it will always jump to the else part. So the if doesn't seem to tihnk it's empty while that is what I'm getting in the toast(Created in the catch)

```
package com.example.domoticaapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CreateProfile extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
//Declare Variables
DBAdapter myDb;
EditText ipInput, nameInput;
Button save;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_profile);

    ipInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipInput);
    nameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(this);

}



private void saveProfile()
{
    String IP = ipInput.getText().toString();
    String name = nameInput.getText().toString();

    if(IP == null || name == null || IP == "" || name == "")
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Name and IP can't be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {

        try
        {
            myDb.insertRow(name, IP);
            //Intent i = new Intent("com.example.domoticaapp.SQLView");
            //startActivity(i);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.save:
                saveProfile();
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: -1 i really do not like question like this("find NPE in my own code") `myDb` is null... why? where did you assign `myDb`?

Comment: post your logcat output

Comment: Check with your layout name in setContentView(). Is that layout have those EditText Components?

Comment: You never initialize DBAdapter

Comment: Which line do you get the null pointer exception on?

Comment: Don't seen any problem in logcat. isn't showing any error besides span cannot have a zero length(because I use a swipe)

Also myDb isn't the problem here I intitialized it and still not working, Because of the if statement I already knew it wasn't the myDb problem. It's a problem that the if statement doesn't seem to tihnk the variables are empty, while the try/catch does(If i put try catch in the if instead of the else it will not execute that one anymore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
if(!IP.equals("") && !name.equals(""))
{
     /** Your Code **/
}
else
{
     Toast.makeText(this, "Name and IP can't be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name ) &&TextUtils.isEmpty(IP)){
  Toast....
}else{
  ...
}
```

Comment: This actually worked
Could you explain what the difference is? Since my check should do the same right? Or is it missing something?

Answer (score -2):

```
DBAdapter myDb;
```

myDb has not been intialised. You just declared it

Comment: Thank you, Cpt. Obvious! edit: does the one who give me +1 for this comment know that this is irony?